# ruby on rails: ordering index of topics based on polymorphic associated comments not showing the right data when rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, forum

I'm building a basic forum application in Ruby on Rails (v4.1.7) and I'm having an issue with displaying the topics in descending order based on their last post.  The code I'm using below will show the topics in the correct descending order, however the last post times and last poster name are wrong.

When I view the topic with comments#index, these data are correct.  Both comments#index and topics#index call the same partial to display the topic:

I believe this may have to do with me calling topic.comments.last
Testing it out, it seems to be displaying the FIRST comments userdata and created_at, rather than the last, however the forums ARE showing up in the correct order.

Partial: _topic.html.erb:

```
<article class="topic">
  <h2><%= link_to(topic.title, topic_comments_path(topic)) %></h2>
  <div class="author">
    By <strong><%= topic.user.name %> </strong>
       on <%= topic.created_at.strftime('%b %d %Y') %>
  </div>
  <div class="stats">
    Viewed <%= pluralize(topic.view_count, 'time') %>.
    <% if topic.comments.any? %>
      Last comment <%= time_ago_in_words(topic.comments.last.created_at) %> ago
      by <%= topic.comments.last.user.name %>.
    <% else %>
      No comments.
    <% end %>
    <span class="pull-right">
      <%= pluralize(topic.comments.count, 'comment') %>.
    </span>
  </div>
</article>
```

topics_controller#index (produces incorrect data):

```
def index
  @topics = Topic.includes(:comments).order('comments.created_at desc')
end
```

I have also attempted:

```
def index
  @topics = Topic.includes(:comments).paginate(page: params[:page]).order('comments.created_at desc')
end
```

topics/index.html.erb(wrong data):

```
<% provide(:title, 'Forum Index') %>
<%= render partial: @topics, spacer_template: 'shared/hr' %>
```

Viewing a specific thread (in this case the topic.comments.last.user.name and topic.comments.last.created_at are the correct values):

```
def index
  @context = context
  @comments = @context.comments.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
#...
private
  def context
    Topic.find(params[:topic_id]) if params[:topic_id]
  end
```

topics/index.html.erb (right data):

```
<% provide(:title, @context.title) %>
<h1>View Discussion</h1>
<%= render(partial: 'topics/topic', object: @context) %>  # Partial with right data
<hr />
<%= render(partial: 'comment',
           collection: @comments,
           spacer_template: 'shared/hr',
           locals: { topic: @context }) || 'No comments.' %>

<hr />
<%= render partial: 'comment_form', locals: { context: @context,
                                              comment: @context.comments.new } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
topic.comments.last
```

should be

```
topic.comments.first
```

because you're placing the latest comments first.

Where it's working fine, it is because you aren't ordering the comments and the `last` will fetch the comment with the highest primary index value which is most likely the ID.

Hope that clears it up.

And just FYI:

```
topic.comments.count
```

will fire up another query in your view. Change the `count` to `size`

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the tip on using .size().  Is there a simple way to grab the latest comment bared on created_at so that I can  continue to reuse the partial in both views?

Comment: No problem. Mark my answer as the selected one, vote it up, and vote up this comment if they help. And you should simply specify the same order clause in both actions i.e. `comments.created_at DESC`. Then it should work the same.

Comment: I'm retesting it, and one issue is now in the view when viewing a single topic the comments are backwards due to .order(created_at: :desc)  Is there a simple way to keep them in order after the relation is reloaded?

I have a simple workaround using a last_comment field in the topic model, but I'm not a fan of having this as it represents data in another model.

Passing a conditional to the partial seems to be one way to fix it, however I'm not sure that's following MVC well.

Comment: Well, they're obviously only going to be in order that you've specified. You could reverse them by loading them as an array and then calling the reverse method. `topic.comments.reverse`